# Is it possible to add padding to css border property?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kkbdex3p/) look more like this: http://i.imgur.com/8FxmAeR.jpg

More specifically, what I notice is that in the image, the borders between the sections appear to have this padding on the top and bottom, so that the border is not full height. Is it possible to do this in my jsfiddle example, i.e. make the red borders have a padding on top and bottom so they aren't full height?

I've thought of adding a new element like so:

```
<li class="divider"></li>
```

And maybe trying to style that (1px wide, padding on top and bottom), but I get weird results and I'd love a css only solution if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `:after` psuedo-element to achieve this:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

li:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    content: '';
    margin: 0 -20px;
}

li:first-child:after { display: none; }
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkbdex3p/1/)